# Dynamic queries using Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> and EntityFramework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've been writing a piece of code that will allow you to define a number of properties on an entity to search through. This was quite simple, however where it falls over is when you begin to use expressions such as:

```
this.HasColumn(e => e.FirstName + e.LastName, "FullName")
```

instead of just:

```
this.HasColumn(e => e.FirstName, "FirstName")
```

I've got a mockup of an expression that works using Expression.Call which is this:

```
BinaryExpression memberExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Add, Expression.Property(pe, "FirstName"), Expression.Property(pe, "LastName"));
```

This is the code I have as it is:

```
public IQueryable<T> Search(string valueToSearch, IQueryable<T> unfilteredList)
{
    valueToSearch = valueToSearch.Replace(" ", "");

    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null;

    foreach (var propertyName in this.Columns)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = null;
        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

        Expression member = parameterExpression;

        var canConvert = canConvertToType(valueToSearch, member.Type.FullName);

        if (canConvert)
        {
            var value = convertToType(valueToSearch, member.Type.FullName);
            if (IsString)
            {
                ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
                var memberExpression = Expression.Add(Expression.Property(pe, "FirstName"), Expression.Property(pe, "LastName"), typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }));


                Expression replaceMethodCall = Expression.Call(propertyName.Target, typeof(string).GetMethod("Replace", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }), Expression.Constant(" ", typeof(string)), Expression.Constant("", typeof(string)));

                MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
                ConstantExpression constantExpression = Expression.Constant(valueToSearch, typeof(string));

                Expression call = Expression.Call(replaceMethodCall, methodInfo, constantExpression);

                lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, pe);
            }
            else
            {
                lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(propertyName.Target.Body, Expression.Constant(value)), parameterExpression);
            }
        }

        if (lambda != null)
        {
            if (expression == null)
            {
                expression = lambda;
            }
            else
            {
                expression = PredicateBuilder.Or(expression, lambda);
            }
        }
    }

    if (expression != null)
    {
        return unfilteredList.Where(expression);
    }

    // return an empty set
    return new List<T>().AsQueryable();
}
```

Where am I going wrong with this? And why can't I just use my `Expression<Func<TEntity, string>>` as part of this?

EDIT: This line:

```
Expression replaceMethodCall = Expression.Call(propertyName.Target, typeof(string).GetMethod("Replace", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }), Expression.Constant(" ", typeof(string)), Expression.Constant("", typeof(string)));
```

Generates this exception:

```
Additional information: Method 'System.String Replace(System.String, System.String)' declared on type 'System.String' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Func`2[GlobalSearchTest.Person,System.String]'
```

Comment: You are doing a `Replace` and a `Contains`... have you checked the EF supports them? If you build in code a `.Where()` with them and execute it, do they work?

Comment: @xantos I should have included the exception. I've included the line which causes the exception and the exception itself now. I can also guarantee Replace and Contains works correctly with EF.

Comment: Your code smells fishy... How will it be called? Because your example is `this.HasColumn(e => e.FirstName + e.LastName, "FullName")`, but then you do a `Search(string valueToSearch, IQueryable<T> unfilteredList)` that uses a `foreach (var propertyName in this.Columns)` where it isn't clear what `this.Columns` is